# Neto API Limitations

Tags: e-commerce, neto

I'm currently attempting to integrate with the Neto Ecommerce API. I've hit all sorts of limitations that I never see on other platforms and the latest is to do with custom fields.

The API Im using is the GetOrders API, and Im following the requirements to fetch transaction information, however custom fields appear to be missing. Hoping someone out there has made use of this API to extract custom fields and can advise on how to go about getting custom field information.

Any tips appreciated

```
var netoString = '{"Filter":{"OrderID":[""],"OutputSelector":["ID","ShippingOption","DeliveryInstruction","RelatedOrderID","cust1"]};
```

Is there an undocumented naming convention used to fetch custom fields or other pattern I can try to see if I can fetch the data?

Answer (score 0):

I am not certain this will be the same for the API, but when using exports the correct format to access Custom Sales Order Fields is "customer_ref1".

To get a Custom Customer Fields is "usercustom1"

Note: For the Custom Customer Fields, the numbers do not match up correctly (I.E. usercustom1 doesn't match misc1 in the cpanel). The correct matches are:

- misc1=usercustom1
- misc2=usercustom4
- misc3=usercustom5
- misc4=usercustom6
- misc5=usercustom7
- misc6=usercustom11
- misc7=usercustom12
- misc8=usercustom13
- misc9=usercustom14
- misc10=usercustom15
- misc11=usercustom16
- misc12=usercustom17
- misc13=usercustom18
- misc14=usercustom19
- misc15=usercustom20
- misc16=usercustom21
- misc17=usercustom22
- misc18=usercustom23
- misc19=usercustom24
- misc20=usercustom25
- misc21=usercustom10
- misc22=usercustom26
- misc23=usercustom27
- misc24=usercustom28
- misc25=usercustom29
- misc26=usercustom30
- misc27=usercustom31
- misc28=usercustom32
- misc29=usercustom33
- misc30=usercustom34
- misc31=usercustom35
- misc32=usercustom36
- misc33=usercustom37
- misc34=usercustom38
- misc35=usercustom39
- misc36=usercustom40

Comment: I'm looking for someone who know Neto. Do you do development?

Comment: I do, how can I help?

Comment: Can you ping me on Skype using my username?